# Silver Searcher errors out when I try and do a search

Tags: vim, command-line

Silver Searcher (v2.2.0) throws the following error when I try and do a search:

```
Error detected while processing function TheSilverSearcher:
line    1:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: 
python3 << endPython
line    3:
E492: Not an editor command: import vim
line    5:
E492: Not an editor command: def python_input(message = 
'input'):
line    6:
E682: Invalid search pattern or delimiter
line    7:
E682: Invalid search pattern or delimiter
line    8:
E682: Invalid search pattern or delimiter
line    9:
E121: Undefined variable: vim
E15: Invalid expression: vim.eval('user_input')
```

I tried reinstalling and updating my version of the_silver_searcher, but I keep getting the same error. I checked the settings of a coworker and they have the same setup. How can I get the search working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be `brew uninstall vim`, then `brew install vim --with-lua --with-python3`.